# Count lines < value where previous line was > value

Tags: awk

I have a data set as such:

```
3.3362994
3.3468399
3.3524561
3.3526943
3.2417695
3.3313386
3.3288026
3.3173411
3.3031421
3.2790108
3.3720325
3.2597685
3.2472827
3.2393241
```

I would like to count the number of times a line is < 3.3 but only if the previous line is > 3.3. I have tried

```
awk '$1 < 3.3 && prev > 3.3 {c++} END { print c+0 }'
```

but it sends back 0, which is incorrect.

Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Sure, but set `prev` somewhere after you used it. Like `... {c++}  { prev = $0 }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could try:

```
awk 'BEGIN{prev = 0; count=0} {if($1 < 3.3 && prev > 3.3)count = count+1; prev=$1} END {print count}' inputFile.txt
```